# Tensorflow Pip Install Mac/Docker Python3

Tags: macos, docker, pip, python-3.8, tensorflow2.x

I am currently trying to install tensorflow inside of a Docker container or on my local Macbook. Both are not working and return the same result: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

I am using a normal pip install. Docker: `RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`
Mac: `pip3 install tensorflow`

My pip versions are all up to date since I ran `pip install --upgrade pip` a lot of times so far and do it again with every new try.

I am not able to change the Python version in the Docker-Container since there are other packages which require Python 3.8 in the same Container.

I am happy for any Ideas to solve that problem other than updating pip oder installing another Python version since that is not possible for me.

My System is a Macbook Air 2020 M1.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a faster and more accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have now found the answer to my own question. The answer is postet in this Stackoverflow link: [Tensorflow not found on pip install inside Docker Container using Mac M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206026/tensorflow-not-found-on-pip-install-inside-docker-container-using-mac-m1)

You need to change the platform to linux when running the docker command. `docker build --platform linux/x86_64 -t myimage .`

Comment: Hi Jake - I did this, but then I get an error `qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped` after `import tensorflow`. How do you use tensorflow inside the docker container? Any help would be highly appreciated (I am on a Mac M1)

Comment: Yes I am using tensorflow inside of a Docker container but I still could'nt get my code running properly. I only got so far to build the Image but there are still bugs in my code I need to fix. But to build the container, I added a Dockerfile, Python file and requirements file and used the command I mentioned above. That did'nt work for you? Do you have these three files and are in the right directory when entering the command?

Comment: Hi Jake, I do have those files, but still had the mentioned error. Anyway, I replaced that part of the code with an equivalent PyTorch version and I am good for now. Thanks for answering